# Open source alternative to Moodle CodeRunner?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, programming

We are planning to implement a coding (programming) platform and below are the requirements:

- There will be three sets or levels of questions (Easy, Medium, Hard).
- When creating a test or contest, it should be pickup two from easy, two from medium and two from hard randomly.
- There should be time limit for every test or contest.
- There should be an option to give optional test cases (which will be shown along with question) and score giving test cases.
- For any question, a user can submit the answer in any one of the supported programming languages (we are planning to target Python, C, C++ and Java).

We are able to achieve everything with Moodle Quiz and [CodeRunner](https://moodle.org/plugins/qtype_coderunner) plugins, except that we are able to give only one programming language option to the user to submit a question.

Is there any open source alternative solution for that which supports our requirements?

Answer (score 1):

With some effort you can actually write your own CodeRunner question type that accepts submissions in multiple languages. See  the forum discussion at http://coderunner.org.nz/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=73. It includes an example question type that accepts either Python or C. The two major caveats are:

1. The template code has to be able to determine the language of the submitted code, either by analysing it or by requiring a language-identifying comment at the start.
2. The Ace editor will probably have to be turned off, as it doesn't know what language the student is using.

When I have some development time - hopefully before the end of the year - I intend adding an optional dropdown box to allow students to choose a language; that should overcome both those problems.

Richard/Trampgeek (CodeRunner developer)

Comment: Umm.... as a teacher (linux admin and programming), and Canvas admin, is there any chance of a stand alone timed exercise that could be used with non-Moodle systems via LTI? Pro hosted or institution hosted?